# Declaring a DLL inside a Delphi XE5 component

Tags: delphi, dll, components

I'm creating a new component in Delphi, which instantiates a DLL

```
Unit UMyComponent

interface

type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
    ... 
    procedure MyDllCall; 
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

function MyDll: Longint; stdcall; external 'MyDllName.dll' name 'MyFunction'

procedure TMyComponent.MyDllCall;
var
  res: LongInt;
begin
  res:= MyDll;
end;

...

procedure Register;
begin 
 RegisterComponents('My Tab', [TMyComponent]); 
end;

end.
```

I have 2 questions:

1. When I install the component on the IDE it searches for the physical DLL and gives an error if it's not found in path. I'd like the component to look for it when it's going to be effectively used at runtime.
2. Is it possible to have the dll library file name to be set at runtime? i.e:  'MyDllName.dll' could change to '10029.dll' or 'ajjdwawd.dll'

Note that I put DLL declaration in the implementation in order not to expose the function call to callers.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress

Comment: Either use [runtime linking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages#Dynamic_Loading_.28Windows-only.29) (`LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, `FreeLibrary`) or [delay loading](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages#Delayed_Loading) (`delayed`).

Comment: Got it thanks. Appreciate.

Comment: Used delayed and worked like a charm. To change dll name at runtime I'm afraid I have to use LoadLibrary. Thanks folks.

Comment: If you have a new question, click the *Ask Question* button at the top and write a new question. Editing in new information in order to ask a subsequent question after this one was answered is inappropriate. I've rolled back your edit accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code uses what is known as [load-time linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184.aspx). The dependency must be resolved when the module is loaded, otherwise it will fail to load. You need to use the alternative method, [run-time linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090.aspx).

In Delphi there are two ways to do that:

- Use the Win32 directly by calling `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and `FreeLibrary`.
- Get the Delphi RTL to do that for you using the `delayed` keyword.

Both approaches are covered in more detail in the documentation:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/DelayedLoading_(Delphi)

Comment: Question: implemented both delayed and dynamic loading. While the delayed works properly, the dynamic one results in a dll crash and the app closes. I believe that it's related to the params I'm passing to the DLL. They are strings and passed as PAnsiChar. I changed the above post with a param in the way I use it. Do you think it can be related in your experience?

Comment: @Marco: If you have a new, separate question then use the *Ask Question* buttton and ask a new question. The question you asked here has been answered.